# hyperlink on several lines with hyperref

Tags: hyperref

When writing an URL breaking on several lines, the actual link is weird (blue rectangle on the image below) and does not correspond to the sentence. How to fix it?

[image: Example of bad contour for URL]

EDIT:

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

The next sentence is an hyperlink on several lines:
\href{http://www.google.com/}{Click on me to go to the famous webcrawler Google}.

\end{document}
```

In addition, I would like to avoid colored links because the document should be read on screen as well as be printed, and I do want the link and the text to be in black. That is why I prefer the link to be in a rectangle, like in the example above.

Of course, a solution would be to cut the link:

```
 \href{http://www.google.com}{Click on me to go to the}%
 \href{http://www.google.com}{famous webcrawler Google}.
```

but I search for an elegant solution.

Comment: please show a complete small document that shows the problem, it is very hard to debug code you can not see

Answer (score 1):

Forget option `breaklinks`. It is enabled for drivers, that support broken links anyway. Other drivers like `dvips` do **not** support this feature. The the option fixes the output for *printing*, but the link area is broken.

Either compile with a driver, that supports broken links (e.g., `pdflatex`). Or the workaround of the question with manually broken links is a good approach. Broken URLs are supported for `dvips` by package `breakurl`.

A compromise with `colorlinks` would be a dark blue. Then the links can be seen, but they are decent and can be printed without being too light. But also in this case, the links look correct with forced `breaklinks`, but the link areas remain pretty wrong for drivers without support for broken links.

Comment: Compiling with`pdflatex` seems a good solution, thank you. Now I have to change some things to accomodate with ps-tricks.